# Making each column of each DataFrame in a list into its own list within a big list

Tags: python, list, loops, dataframe

**Task Description**

If I have a list of DataFrames in say `a_list` and each list looked like the following:

```
    1  2  3
a   x  x  x
b   y  y  y 
c   z  z  z
```

I am interested in making each column of each DataFrame in `a_list` into its own list.

So say `b_list[0]` would be

```
    1  
a   x 
b   y  
c   z
```

`b_list[1]` would be

```
    2  
a   x 
b   y  
c   z
```

etc.

I currently have around 150 DataFrames in a list with each having 30+ columns. So the desired list would have around `b_list[4500]` Any help with this would be awesome!

Comment: You say you want lists, but the examples you give of the desired lists still very much look like dataframes? Are you sure you want `blist[0] == [<x>, <y>, <z>]`? (I assume `x`, `y` and `z` could be any type in your example). It would help to know what you're trying to achieve, because it seems you're going from a very suitable datatype for most tasks to a datatype that'll be far more cumbersome in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
b_list = []
for df in a_list:
    for col in df.columns:
        b_list.append(df[[col]])
```